# Reading XML file with Invalid character

Tags: c#, xml

I am using Dataset.ReadXML() to read an XML string.  I get an error as the XML string contains the Invalid Character 0x1F which is 'US' - Unit seperator.  This is contained within fully formed tags.

The data is extracted from an Oracle DB, using a Perl script.  How would be the best way to escape this character so that the XML is read correctly.

EDIT: XML String:

```
<RESULT>
<DEPARTMENT>Oncology</DEPARTMENT> 
<DESCRIPTION>Oncology</DESCRIPTION> 
 <STUDY_NAME>**7360C hsd**</STUDY_NAME> 
 <STUDY_ID>27</STUDY_ID> 
</RESULT>
```

Is between the C and h in the bold part, is where there is a US seperator, which when pasted into this actually shows a space.  So I want to know how can I ignore that in an XML string?

Comment: can you post an excerpt of the xml stirng ?

Comment: Have pasted as above, but it has come out very strange?

Comment: you needed to select the XML and press Control-K to put it into a code block. I did it for you.

Comment: Please don't refer to it as an "XML string" when it isn't XML. You need to correct the process that creates the invalid XML, rather than fixing the process that reads it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [section 2.2 of the XML recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets), you'll see that x01F is not in the range of characters allowed in XML documents.  So while the string you're looking at may look like an XML document to you, it isn't one.

You have two problems.  The relatively small one is what to do about this document.  I'd  probably preprocess the string and discard any character that's not legal in well-formed XML, but then I don't know anything about the relatively large problem.

And the relatively large problem is:  what's this data doing in there in the first place?  What purpose (if any) do non-visible ASCII characters in the middle of a (presumably) human-readable data field serve?  Why is it doesn't the Perl script that produces this string failing when it encounters an illegal character?

I'll bet you one American dollar that it's because the person who wrote that script is using string manipulation and not an XML library to emit the XML document.  Which is why, as I've said time and again, you should *never use string manipulation to produce XML*. (There are certainly exceptions.  If you're writing a throwaway application, for instance, or an XML parser.  Or if your name's Tim Bray.)

Comment: The data is legacy data that (apparently) was initially stored in a MS Access file, moved over to SQl and now needs to be available for viewing.  I am using an XML library: http://search.cpan.org/~bholzman/XML-Generator-1.03/Generator.pm, although I have just switched to that, as the previous version was using string manipulation.

Comment: The problem of bad data still there if you use an XML library, but at least you've eliminated the problem of writing "XML strings" that aren't well-formed XML.  You still have to figure out what to do with the bad data and fix it.  But at least now you're fixing it in something approximating the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Your XmlReader/TextReader must be created with correct encoding. You can create it as below and pass to your Dataaset:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("myfile.xml",Encoding.ASCII); // or correct encoding
myDataset.ReadXml(reader);
```

Comment: I get 'illegal characters in path' ?

Comment: That must be from StreamReader and the path you are passing. Double check your path.

Comment: -1 - encoding doesn't save you from random garbage in the data.